# Custom PDF creation - Large images

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

Looking for a Java based PDF creation library. We're currently using Apache Velocity with HTML to render PDFs on the fly.

We'd like to be able to find a way to render large images (sometimes as big as 3000 x 1700) in a creative manner within the PDF container. For instance, a scrollable image pane within a PDF. This might not be possible within a PDF, I might be wrong.

Open source would ideal.

Comment: Given the philosophy of PDF seems aimed towards giving a good **printed** version of the document, I doubt they would offer a form of 'scrollable pane'.  If that is the case, PDF is not well suited to this use.

Comment: *Open source would ideal*. Don't you want a cup of coffee while you wait for answers?

Comment: @Luiggi Shame on you, you forgot the donuts to go with that coffee!

Comment: PDF doesn't support scrollable image panes natively - it _might_ be possible via JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

For a good PDF library you should take a look at iText: http://itextpdf.com/
I have used images of around 5000x4000 with iText without any problems.

I don't know if it is possible to create a working scrollpane inside a PDF, unless of course you were doing it through a custom PDF creator/viewer.

iText is open source but make sure to check out the AGPL license before you use it commecrially: http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php

Comment: Good suggestion - Just wasn't an option based on their licensing.

Comment: Just an update on this for anyone else that finds this question, if you use iText version 2.1.7 or older it falls under the old LGPL license, and has far more free reign and may be suitable for commercial use you are after.

Answer (score 1):

For just creating PDF files from images iText is a little overdimensioned. Give [xsPDF](http://code.google.com/p/xspdf/) a chance, it has no limits for images sizes and seems to be appropriate for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a FYI for anyone that may run into this in the future:

I used a library called PDFBox (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to open a pre-existing PDF and modify the PDF with a custom sized PDFRectangle with the dimensions of the image. Then inserted the image and rectangle into that new page and got the desired results.

I didn't realize you could have multiple page sizes in a single PDF.